# Django group by foreignkey and filter by sum of another field

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Given the model:

```
class Bid(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Account', related_name="bids")
    tokens = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I would like to be able to do two things.

1. Get a sum of tokens per account.
2. Filter accounts based on their sum of tokens.

Because I want to be able to dynamically filter the results in other ways, it would be great to get a queryset back that I can continue to filter. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `annotate()` to [generate aggregates for each item in a QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset). From the Django Docs:

> Per-object summaries can be generated using the `annotate()` clause. **When an `annotate()` clause is specified, each object in the `QuerySet` will be annotated with the specified values.**
>
> Unlike `aggregate()`, `annotate()` is not a terminal clause. **The output of the `annotate()` clause is a QuerySet**; this QuerySet can be modified using any other QuerySet operation, including `filter()`, `order_by()`, or even additional calls to `annotate()`.

Referring to your example, you should be able to use the following to *filter for accounts with a sum of tokens >= 100*:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

# every Account in the Queryset will have an extra attribute called sum_tokens
qs1 = Account.objects.annotate(sum_tokens=Sum('bids__tokens'))

# annotate returns a QuerySet so you can continue to filter it
qs2 = qs1.filter(sum_tokens__gte=100)

# combine the above two to get what you need
qs = Account.objects.annotate(sum_tokens=Sum('bids__tokens')).filter(sum_tokens__gte=100)
```

Comment: Nice, one variation if you have time, what if I'm starting with a subset of the bid objects and want to do the same process, but only using that subset of bid objects to get the sums from?

Comment: Sounds like you can just grab the related `Account`s from that `Bid` subset and then do the above `.annotate().filter()`--you may need to use `.distinct()` to prevent duplicate accounts in the queryset. Try: `bid_subset.account.distinct().annotate( ... ).filter( ... )`